# Is it possible to run a function as a process in rust?

Tags: rust

The rust `std::process::Command`; structure take in a `Command::new(program)`, where program is the path to the program to be executed as shown in the example below.

```
let output = if cfg!(target_os = "windows") {
    Command::new("cmd")
            .args(&["/C", "echo hello"])
            .output()
            .expect("failed to execute process")
```

Is it possible to create a new process on windows in rust to run a function?

Comment: Could use https://docs.rs/nix/0.15.0/nix/unistd/fn.fork.html if you're on a compatible platform and know a bit about `fork`. I haven't been able to locate a higher-level interface a la Python's `multiprocessing.Process`.

Comment: This begs a crucial question. As a function does not necessarily have a status return code the way a process does... Are you sure you need a process and not a thread?

Comment: Yeah you can use `fork()` but it's terrible complicated, error-prone and platform specific. You should almost certainly avoid it and just use a thread or shared memory or command line arguments instead.

Answer (score 1):

In short, you cannot, creating a new process needs much more information than just the code it will execute. See [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) Windows' system call.

But, you can choose between these alternatives:

1. Create a thread instead.
2. Create a process where the executable is the same program that is running but passing a different argument that triggers the execution of the function you are interested in.
3. Create a [Shared Memory Segment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/creating-named-shared-memory).
4. Create a third library containing your function and share it between your original program and the one you spawn.